# Web-Api authentication problems

Tags: asp.net-web-api

This is my first ASP.NET project and I want to make a easy login.
I tried this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014953/asp-net-web-api-authentication)

but I can't understand basic things:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    public bool Post(LogOnModel model)
    {
        if (model.Username == "john" && model.Password == "secret")
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, false);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

1) How to code a correct call to this controller?

2) Should not somethings like "credentials" or "Username + PW" instead a LogOnModel?

Comment: Do you wanna do forms authentication or token/HTTP Basic authentication?

Comment: I want a forms authentication with:
client: Username: and PW: