# WEB API authentication from different platforms

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-web-roles, asp.net-web-api

I need to create API application which will be accessed from different platforms (WEB, WPF, Mobile). The API will be hosted on Azure and client will be different websites and desktop/mobile applications. API need to know username to return user-specific information

I have some problems with authentication right now. I used idea from [this thread how to do forms authentication to API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014953/asp-net-web-api-authentication), but there is a problem there, I have to authenticate each request to API, because the cookie which I created in previous request is not stored to next request.

I am thinking about creating some custom solution there: when login request to API sent with username/password return some kind of token which i will store on client and will pass with each request. In that case I can override AuthorizeAttribute and validate the token.
but I don't believe then I should create custom solution and prefer to find a way to use something Microsoft did for me.

What will be the best way to authenticate to WEB API from different platforms?
In case if I will return token, what is the best way to create it, encode it, expire it...?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing available out of box currently, to the best of my knowledge. With OWIN, there are things coming up. You can take a look at Katana source code (Microsoft.Owin.Security). For JSON Web Token, Microsoft has the JSON web token [handler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt). More info [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/06/06/the-json-web-token-handler-for-net-4-5-reaches-ga/). The JSON Web Token Handler can both create and validate JWT. You can use the same library to issue and validate JWT respectively from the token issuer and your web API. Creating all these infrastructure is not easy. Thinktecture identity server and identity model can make these tasks easier for you. Both are open source and you can take a look at the source code in github. Check out [this](http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/) and [this](http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45/). Another good resource is Dominick's [blog](http://leastprivilege.com/).

Comment: Adding to Badri's comment, the JWT handler referenced above is one I've used.  This document has an example walkthrough of configuring the Web API.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn169448.aspx#BKMK_Writing1