# How to build an android SDK from c# DLL

Tags: android, api, sdk

I build an Authentication .NET Web API in the way of authenticate HTTP messages using a secret that is known to both client and server, this API can be requested from client side by using the client DLL provided. It is only can be used by c# developer (c/s or b/s),  an android developer need the request to this API, but DLL only can be used by c#. how can I provide a SDK for the android application to use this API. I have no any idea of SDK. Can anyone help me to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As how I understand that is a managed Dll and not a win32 at least.
At this point you need an environment to be able to to read that dll and execute the dll or part. 
This will not a feasible for you but technically: your Adroid easily can ask a PC via web-service, which has windows and able to communicate with your server.

You probably would implement a multiplatform authentication webservice and call it from Android and C# client. Like a simple HTTP Post or use a HTTPS or if you are paranoid than use crypto to encrypt the transmitted message and decrypt at server side. Unfortunately this is not a 2x click task in visual Studio and you have to open a browser to google and enter a few words and visit links...

How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16238211/529543) link to visit first?