# Authentication on web Api using HttpsClient

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I have asp.net web api and 3 web mvc5 project.i m authenticating the users on role bases using identity. how i can pass the authentication of the user from web mvc to my api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014953/asp-net-web-api-authentication

Comment: can i implement role base authentication in the website when i get token from Api?